# Get all phone number from a single contact and set in edittext

Tags: android

I want to get all phone numbers from a selected contact in edittext. My problem is edittext only displays the first phone number of that selected contact. Suppose a contact has two numbers like 12345 and 00001. My edittext only displays the first number 12345 but I'd like 12345,00001.

I'm trying with this:

```
    Cursor cursor = null; 
    String phoneNumber = "";
    int phoneIdx = 0;
    Uri result = data.getData();

    String id = result.getLastPathSegment();
    cursor = getContentResolver().query(Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, Phone.CONTACT_ID + "=?", new String[] { id }, null); 
    phoneIdx = cursor.getColumnIndex(Phone.DATA);
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    else {

    }  
} 
finally {  
    if (cursor != null) {  
        cursor.close();
    }
    final EditText phoneInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.contact_phone);
    nameEntry.setText(phoneNumber);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write

```
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (cursor.isAfterLast() != true) {
        if (phoneNumber.equals("")) {
            phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
        }

        else {
            phoneNumber = phoneNumber + "," + cursor.getString(phoneIdx);   
        }
        cursor.moveToNext();

     }
```

Instead of

```
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                phoneNumber = cursor.getString(phoneIdx);
                    cursor.moveToNext();


            }
```

Comment: Have edited the answer.Use `cursor.isAfterLast()` instead of `cursor.isLast()` . Check if it works now

Comment: thanks bro work fine just little problem.now i get ,12345,00001.how can i remove"," in starting?

Comment: Don't forget to mark his answer, as he basically did your coding for you.